# Running Multi Store on Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, multistore

I'm running two stores in magento 1.7 ..

abc.example.com
xyz.example.com

abc.example.com is the main store and from where I'm using magento admin panel.

in xyz.example i change index file to 
Mage::run($mageRunCode,$mageRunType);
to
Mage::run('xyz_code','xyz.example.com');

but from this I'm redirecting to 404 page. and when i keep first parameter empty like Mage::run('','xyz.example.com'); the web open abc.example.com

any idea what causing that?

Answer (score 0):

Change index file to Mage::run($mageRunCode,$mageRunType); to Mage::run('xyz_code','xyz.example.com'). You need to create symbolic links to point to a few directories.

```
ln -s ../public_html/app ./app
ln -s ../public_html/errors ./errors
ln -s ../public_html/includes ./includes
ln -s ../public_html/js ./js
ln -s ../public_html/lib ./lib
ln -s ../public_html/media ./media
ln -s ../public_html/skin ./skin
ln -s ../public_html/var ./var
```

This might help you. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/multiple-website-setup